# How do I adapt existing responsive web site to display Leaflet maps?

Tags: leaflet, javascript, web-mapping, html, web

My website works well on different devices but it seems that only works with images, although I would like to show other media, like Leaflet maps and videos.

[image: Desktop]

[image: iPad Portrait]

[image: iPad Landscape]

[image: iPhone]

Just about all pages are laid out on a grid using classes.

[image: layout]

Here is the current html code for one image:

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <p class="lead">Cityscapes have a uniquely vibrant feel to them which is unlike any other form of landscape. In creating ours we employ a variety of techniques, including hand drawing, watercolor and digital.</p>
      <br><p class="h5 text-right palette-coral">Downtown Manhattan</p>
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 overlap-sm">
      <p>
        <span class="picturefill-medium" data-picture data-alt="Downtown Manhattan">
          <span data-src="../../img/work/cityscapes/lowerManhattan01_298.jpg"></span>
          <span data-src="../../img/work/cityscapes/lowerManhattan01_482.jpg" data-media="(min-width: 480px)"></span>
          <span data-src="../../img/work/cityscapes/lowerManhattan01_644.jpg" data-media="(min-width: 992px)"></span>
          <noscript>
            <img src="../..../../img/work/cityscapes/lowerManhattan01_298.jpg" alt="Downtown Manhattan">
          </noscript>
        </span>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Each image has three size versions and depending on the width of the viewer's screen the right one is loaded.

In the past I tried to display videos in the same framework (span) but I was not able, so I settled for screen shots with links to an external page to see the video.

Now I want to be able to display Leaflet maps on the same grid but I tried various html code and it didn't work.

For example, I tried the code below, but regardless of the width of the screen the div with 298px is loading:

```
<span class="picturefill-medium" data-picture data-alt="Downtown Manhattan">
  <span><div id="mapid" style="width:298px; height: 298px;"></div></span>
  <span  data-media="(min-width: 480px)"><div id="mapid" style="width:482px; height:482px;"></div></span>
  <span  data-media="(min-width: 992px)"><div id="mapid" style="width:644px; height: 644px;"></div></span>

</span>
```

Any advice?

Comment: Which dynamic framework are you using? How do other web sites behave in your framework?

Comment: Maybe I misused the term "framework". There are no other sites, just this one.

Comment: I didn't formulate my question clearly enough. What I'm interested in is how other web sites (not Leaflet based) behave if you put them in your framework in place where you want to put Leaflet based site?

Answer (score 1):

You need to define an absolute `height` on the parent element and then you can set `height: 100%` on the map container:

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 300px;
}

#map {
  height: 100%;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/newluck77/Lc7dwk1o/)

So in your case the HTML should look like this:

```
<span style="width:298px; height: 298px;"><div id="mapid" style="height: 100%;"></div></span>
```

If you encounter weird things when you change orientation of the device, you should call [`invalidateSize()`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#map-invalidatesize) on the map.